# Does this clause require an article or not?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

I am confused about whether to add an article before clarification or not?

1. "I asked for clarification on the legal position"

Or

2. "I asked for a clarification on the legal position"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **I asked for clarification on the legal position.**
>
> **I asked for a clarification  on the legal position.**

I think both are correct and mean the same thing.

Clarification is both countable and uncountable.

Here is a link which shows how *clarification* can be used  with or without an article:

https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/sentences-with-the-word/clarification.html

Here is another link for further clarification about the word *clarification*:

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/clarification

Comment: How can be countable and uncountable?

Comment: @Abu - It's actually not all that uncommon. See [this language blog](https://www.espressoenglish.net/words-that-are-both-countable-and-uncountable/) for more examples.